# I am getting some error when I am trying to start running jabaco project

Tags: java, jabaco

I load Jabaco, and open a new sdi project.and then, I click the "Project" menu and "Start" with no result.but a txt file show in my desktop name:hs_err_pid9900.log

Some Extracts of the log:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x7c343023, pid=9900,
>   tid=10016
>
> JRE version: 6.0_27-b07  Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
>   (20.2-b06 mixed mode windows-x86 )  Problematic frame:  C 
>   [msvcr71.dll+0x3023]

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Answer (score 0):

A similar error was [posted and discussed](http://www.jabaco.org/board/p1615-jabaco-error.html#post1615) in the Jabaco forum.

Jabaco is an interesting project to allow VB6 developers to shift towards and use Java. However, due to the fact that is is relying on a single developer, Jabaco is not always up-to-date w.r.t. to the latest Windows and Java environments.

Your msvcr71.dll might be corrupted or outdated. Try to use an elder Java Runtime earlier than 6.0_24
My last Jabaco experiments worked on Windows XP. If you have a more recent Windows, you might have trouble in general using Jabaco.